# Laravel y el formateo de fechas

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Señores estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla con Eloquent...y entre los campos que quiero consultar esta uno de fecha, como hago para que en plena consulta traer la fecha formateada? Ej:

```
$consulta=Ejemplo::select('fecha')->find($id);
```

estoy buscado el campo fecha pero esta en mm-dd-yyyy ,quiero presentarlo como dd-mm-yyyy como se hace?

Answer (score 2):

Las fechas en Laravel son convertidas (normalmente) a instancias de Carbon, al menos en las versiones recientes, en teoría simplemente debes usar el método`format()` en la instancia de Carbon, o sea, en el campo como tal:

```
$consulta->fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

Comment: Necesito un poco mas de ayuda te comento...yo estoy haciendo una consulta a un formulario de tipo model en laravel...es decir para hacer una edición....cuando yo ejecuto la consulta en eloquent la estoy haciendo asi: $consulta=Ejemplo::findOrFail($id); y como debes de saber cuando se visita la vista por ser de tipo model me muestra toda la información en el formulario.....como haria para hacer eso que me estas diciendo??? es decir como aplico ese formato en ese momento.???

Comment: Eso es un problema distinto, relacionado pero no el mismo de la pregunta actual. Sugiero que aceptes esta respuesta que debería solucionar el problema que comentas y formular una nueva con el "nuevo problema".

Answer (score 1):

No se si mi respuesta llegue tarde. Pero laravel en sus versiones modernas trae los **mutadores** por defecto. Es como logra pasar los **timestamp** a instancias de **Carbon**

Si tu deseas **mutar** siempre las fechas y vas hacer las consultas con el modelo entonces podrías implementar el **mutador** en el **modelo.**

Este es un ejemplo muy sencillo.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Site;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ejemplo extends Model
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    }
}
```

Estas dos **métodos** lo que aran es **mutar** los atributos del **timestamp.** Es decir, si normalmente cuando haces una consulta con el **modelo**  **Ejemplo** y obtienes el siguiente resultado:

```
//consulta
Ejemplo::find(1)->toArray();
//resultado
[
    "created_at" => "2020-03-14T09:33:34.000000Z", 
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-14T09:33:34.000000Z"
]
```

Después de aplicar las mutaciones lo que devolver la misma consulta sera:

```
//consulta
Ejemplo::find(1)->toArray();
//resultado
[
    "created_at" => "14-03-2020 09:33:34", 
    "updated_at" => "14-03-2020 09:33:34"
]
```

Inclusive puedes utilizar los **mutadores** para hacer formatos mas específicos sobre como ordenar la data para responderla directamente desde una API.

Te recomiendo leer la documentación completa de los **Modelos** para que le puedas sacar todo el juego a Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

- Considera hacer uso de Eloquent y los modelos
- Puedes hacer uso de la propiedad `cast` para dejar un formato permanente
- Este formato que elijas será siempre y cuando en tus consultas hagas uso del modelo
- Cómo clave del vector asociativo pasas el nombre de la columna s formatear

Así

```
protected $casts = [
    'fecha' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
];
```